# Hibernate how to Add Check Constraints

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, check-constraints

I have a field at my Java side:

```
@Column(name = "ads", length = 60, nullable = false)
protected String name;
```

so it has an effect at SQL (I use PostgreSQL) side:

```
"ads" character varying(60) NOT NULL
```

However I want to add check constraint to it as like:

```
"ads" character varying(60) NOT NULL CHECK (ads <> '')
```

How can I define it at Java(hibernate) side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `@NotEmpty` annotation on your field.

```
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "ads", length = 60, nullable = false)
    protected String name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Check](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Check.html) annotation. Beware that according the [this bug report](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4315), it only works at class level.